# How to select a row from a 2D tuple

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

This is probably a very straightforward thing but I can't get it.

How do you go about selecting *"rows"* (I use the word row for lack of a better one) from a 2D (or nD) tuple?

```
A = [0,1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6,7]
C = (A,B)
```

I.E., how do I get the result `([1,2],[5,6])` from C?

I've tried `C[:][1:2]` but I get the result `([4, 5, 6, 7],)`

Comment: `C[0][1:3], C[1][1:3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a comprehension:

```
tuple(x[1:3] for x in C)
```

Comment: I like this, though the slice should be `x[1:3]`

Comment: @AndyKubiak  Thanks! I took the slice indices from OP at face value

Comment: Thank you, this is it. My indexes were wrong, thank you for pointing that out as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also map `itemgetter` passing whatever indexes you want to get:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(map(itemgetter(1,2),C)))
[(1, 2), (5, 6)]
```